# Paned Window Resizing Issues

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying out panedWindows for my app layout, but I'm having issues when the window resizes. This is the layout I've started out with:
[image: initial layout]

The panes drag as I want them too, but I want to specify what panes expand to fill the root window, and which ones stay a specific width. For example, when I drag the window to the right or left, the pane on the expanding size extends to fill the extra space. I want only the centre pane to expand, and the right and left only when the sash is dragged:

[image: what happens when resizing window]

like this:

[image: desired behaviour when resizing window]

When the panes were managed with the pack geometry manager, I could tell the edge panes to stay a specific width, and tell the centre pane to expand. How can I achieve a similar layout with paned windows?

Heres a minimal working example:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("480x200+200+200")
root.title("Paned Window Example")

main = tkinter.PanedWindow()

main.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")

pane1 = tkinter.Frame(width = 90, bg = "red")
pane2 = tkinter.Frame(width = 310, bg = "blue")
pane3 = tkinter.Frame(width = 90, bg = "red")

for pane in pane1, pane2, pane3 : main.add(pane)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `stretch` option when adding the panes to the `PanedWindow`. It takes the following values:  'always', 'first', 'last', 'middle', and 'never'.
You can get a more complete description in the [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/panedwindow.htm#M36).

In your case, use 'never' for the side panes and 'always' for the middle one:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("480x200+200+200")
root.title("Paned Window Example")

main = tkinter.PanedWindow()

main.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

pane1 = tkinter.Frame(width=90, bg="red")
pane2 = tkinter.Frame(width=310, bg="blue")
pane3 = tkinter.Frame(width=90, bg="red")

main.add(pane1, stretch='never')
main.add(pane2, stretch='always')
main.add(pane3, stretch='never')

root.mainloop()
```

Note that the above solution works only for `tkinter.PanedWindow` and not for `ttk` version of the widget. The `.add()` method of `ttk.PanedWindow` accepts only one option: `weight`. But we can achieve the same result by setting the side panes' weight to 0 and the middle pane's to 1:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("480x200+200+200")
root.title("Paned Window Example")

main = ttk.PanedWindow(orient='horizontal')

main.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

pane1 = tkinter.Frame(width=90, bg="red")
pane2 = tkinter.Frame(width=310, bg="blue")
pane3 = tkinter.Frame(width=90, bg="red")

main.add(pane1, weight=0)
main.add(pane2, weight=1)
main.add(pane3, weight=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works perfectly.